# Whats the status of Prism integration in Autofac?

Tags: prism, ioc-container, autofac, prism-4

Integration into Prism was talked about in the 2.1.x time frame, we are @ 2.4.x, Prism 4 is out now and the RIStockTrader Example in /contrib is just a default XAML project.

Should it work? If so, anyone have a simple example of a Silverlight Shell + Bootstrapper + 1 Module they could point me to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An updated Prism integration is currently in progress. I'm not sure what the status is exactly, but you can get the code and potentially contact the author [here](https://code.google.com/r/simonhewitt-prism/source/browse). You can also pass on feedback/suggestions/issues via the [Autofac discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/autofac).

Comment: Thanks! Its hard to find all these extension projects.