# Autofac integration into Prism 4

Tags: prism, autofac, prism-4

I am swapping out the standard Unity container in Prism 4 and run into a problem when my modules are initializing. Before I used to get an IUnityContainer injected and this then allowed me to register additional types from my module all well and good.

Now I am injecting an AutoFac.IContainer and it does not have the RegisterType methods i need. They are located in the ContainerBuilder class.

So the simple question is how to I register types into my main container from within my modules as they are loaded.

Thanks
Craig

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run-Time Registration With Autofac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173566/run-time-registration-with-autofac) *which also discusses Prism*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard Autofac way is [building your modules](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules) as `IModule` classes, using `builder.RegisterModule` to load them into your container as part of the register process.

If you already have a container and need to add registrations to it, you use the `ContainerBuilder` again like this:

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.Register(...);
...

cb.Update(existingContainer);
```